# TensorFlow import warning in Python 3.6 IDLE, macOS

Tags: python, tensorflow

- OS: MacOS High Seirra
- Python version: 3.6.6
- virtualenv version: 16.0.0
- Tensorflow version: 1.10.1
- pip version: pip 18.0
- IDE: Python IDLE (that comes pre installed with Python)

Getting warning while importing TensorFlow:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/ 
python3.6/ 
importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 219
return f(*args, **kwds)
RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 
'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match 
runtime version 3.6
```

Comment: Please read the warning message: your TensorFlow was built targetting Python 3.5, and is being run under 3.6. You can choose to rebuild TensorFlow under 3.6 to get rid of this; the most reliable way to do this would be to do e.g. `python3.6 -m pip install tensorflow`, or using a `pip3.6 install tensorflow` if you have `pip3.6` aliased properly.

Comment: (Having said that, this warning can very likely be ignored; AFAIK 3.6 didn't drop or rename any of the API since 3.5)